# What are the download stats for elementary OS?

Tags: download, stats

I am just curious, on http://blog.elementary.io/post/128271333121/freya-031-is-here you can find this statement:

> "We’re very proud to share some elementary OS download stats as well!
>   So far, elementary OS has been downloaded an estimated 5 million
>   times."

Are those 5 million downloads just for the 0.3.1 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost a year later, I can answer no, these are total downloads for all tracked versions, not just that point release.